# Room cannot be joined for the second time | Photon Unity Networking 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I've implemented joining and leaving rooms in PUN2
If you try to join the room a second time, it will not load.

The following code is a scene that returns from the game scene to the home.

Home.online in the code is always true.

```
public void LeaveRoom()
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.InRoom)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
    }
}

public void GoHome()
{
    if (Home.online)
        LeaveRoom();
}

public override void OnLeftRoom()
{
    ScneManager.LoadScene("Home");
}
```

And the following code is the game scene code.
It is loaded from the home scene with **SceneManager.LoadScene()**.

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("A");
    PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    Debug.Log("B");
}

public override void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    Debug.Log("F");
}
```

This code does not show "F" in debugging.
The second time, OnJoinedRoom() is not executed.

No errors occurred.

Various processing is written after **PhotonNetwork.ConnectusingSettings();**.

Is this game scene properly initialized with **ScneManager.LoadScene("Home");**
I don't know what to do. Please tell us any other information you need.

Please.

Comment: hi @Beginner_, thank you for choosing Photon! this looks like a Unity issue and not related to Photon. Maybe the script where you have the "A" and "B" in `Start` is marked as DontDestroyOnLoad or is a singleton so it persists the first time the scene is loaded and thus Start will be called once.

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried again, but it seems that debugging was called. I did not notice that Unity debug was overwritten. The real problem is the second **public override void OnJoinedRoom() Was not called**. The first OnJoinedRoom () is executed.